# Maven RPM Plugin accepting user input

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

is it possible to map user input from the preInstallScriptlet tag into the directory tag?

```
<mapping>
    <directory>${install.basedir}</directory>
</mapping>
...
<preinstallScriptlet>
    <script>
        read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " install.basedir;
        echo "Installing to " $install.basedir;
    </script>
</preinstallScriptlet>
...
```

Comment: if this is not possible directly in the scriptlet, might it be possible to set in this case TOMCAT_HOME in a shell script if it did not already exist and then use that environment variable as the directory?

Comment: so my second hypothesis worked.  I created a variable and exported it as an environment variable.  Then in the directory tag I added ${env.TOMCAT_HOME}

Comment: As far as i know a RPM should never be interactive.